# Codeigniter Active record query

Tags: sql, codeigniter, activerecord

How can I write this procedural query as codeigniter active record query (update_batch mode )

```
  UPDATE products SET current_stock = current_stock + 1 where product_id = 1
```

Comment: You don't need to use update_batch for this. Update batch is useful when you want to change several record in one query. For instance, in your query if you want to change the stock value of couple product then you can do it with update_batch.

Comment: I want to update multiple record .

Comment: Alright, I changed the query. I think it's better if you add "update_batch" to the title so it can be useful for others.

Answer (score 2):

You can use update_batch like this:

```
$products = $this->db->get('products'))->result(); 
for( $i = 0; $i < count($products); $i++){
$data[] = array(
                   'product_id' => $product[$i]->product_id,
                   'current_stock' => $product[$i]->current_stock + 1
               );
}
$this->db->update_batch('products', $data, 'product_id');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below query as explained on [Codeigniter Query Builder Class](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html#updating-data):

```
$this->db->set('current_stock', 'current_stock+1', FALSE);
$this->db->where('product_id', 2);
$result = $this->db->update('products');
```